# Can't figure how to identify WiFi adapter

Tags: wifi, software-installation, connection

I've got a [Cisco Linksys wireless module AE1200](http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/adapters/AE1200) and I need to connect it to my new Raspberry Pi in order to connect wirelessly.

When I type the `lsusb` command it appears but the flashing led is never on.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have not installed the WiFi drivers for your card yet.  [This link here can guide you through that](http://www.raspberryshake.com/raspberry-pi-wireless-network-setup/).  I'll summarize it here though.

1. Find out the name of our device so we can find the necessary drivers.

   ```
   $ lsusb
   ```

   The result may differ depending on the devices you have attached.

   > Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8189 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. **RTL8187B**
   >   Wireless 802.11g Network adapter.
2. You will need to update your package information.  Be sure that you’re network cable is plugged in as we need to get some updates from Debian.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. When the updates have finished downloading, we are going to search for our driver.

   ```
   $ apt-cache search RTL818
   ```

   Remember your device may be different, so you will be entering your device ID for your device.  You may have noticed that I only entered RTL818 instead of the whole ID.  This is because it didn’t find the adapter when using the apt-cache command.  You may need to shorten your description.

   The result returned for my device was:

   > Firmware-realtek – Binary firmware for Realtek wired and wireless
   >   network adapters
4. Install the drivers.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
   ```

   After a few minutes of updating you will be back at your command prompt.
5. Enter the following command to see if your adapter is listed.

   ```
   $ lsmod
   ```

   You will see the same ID of your device listed.

   ```
   Module                                Size        Used by

   rtl8187                                 44897          0
   ```
6. Create a configuration file for the wireless adapter.

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/wpa.config
   ```

   Now enter the following, save the file and exit back to the $ prompt

   ```
   network={

   ssid=”YOUR_SSID”

   proto=RSN

   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

   pairwise=CCMP TKIP

   group=CCMP TKIP

   psk=”WPA-PASSWORD”

   }
   ```
7. The last part of this configuration is to add a reference to the interfaces.

   ```
    $ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
   ```

   Add the following

   ```
   auto wlan0

   iface wlan0 inet dhcp

   wpa-conf /etc/wpa.config
   ```
8. Restart the network.

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
   ```

Comment: An excellent answer generally, but unfortunately no drivers exist for the rpi with the chipset used in the ae1200 (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your adapter but I have 2 of these and they worked immediately out of the box using the standard Raspbian distribution.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003MTTJOY/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY)

Also, make sure you are giving enough power to your raspi.  Some devices may require more than others.  For instance, I originally had a 750mAh power adapter and that wasn't enough to power both the wifi card and the logitech unity receiver that I use.  I moved to a 2.1Ah adapter (using my ipad) and suddenly everything went smoothly.

Comment: thx for ur response :) i'm using 750mA power Adapter too and ill try to increase it by switching the adapter but u wrote that u use 2.1 A? or u meant 1.2A? cause i read that RPi can't handle that input (the 2 A and above)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did mean 2.1. I don't want to recommend you to do something that could fry your pi but I'm using the Apple 2.1A charger (iPad) for both my pi's and they seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Buy another adapter.

The AE1200 does not appear to have Linux support.[1] Some people have gotten it to work on Ubuntu on intel-based systems by using ndiswrapper around the Windows drivers, but that option is not available for the ARM chipset that is used by the rpi.[2]

[1] https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Linksys_AE1200

[2] https://askubuntu.com/questions/100090/how-do-i-install-the-driver-for-my-linksys-ae1200-wireless-n-usb-adapter